# Overloading less than operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am overloading a less than operator for a class like so:

```
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class X{
public:
    X(long a, string b, int c);
    friend bool operator< (X& a, X& b);

private:
    long a;
    string b;
    int c;
};
```

and then the implementation file:

```
#include "X.h"


bool operator < (X const& lhs, X const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.a< rhs.a;
}
```

However it is not letting me access the `a` data member in the implementation file because `a` is declared as a private data member, even though its through an `X` object?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The friend function does not have the same signature as the function defined function:

```
friend bool operator< (X& a, X& b);
```

and

```
bool operator < (X const& lhs, X const& rhs)
//                 ^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

You should just change the line in your header file to:

```
friend bool operator< ( X const& a, X const& b);
//                        ^^^^^       ^^^^^
```

As you don't modify the objects inside the comparison operators, they should take const-references.

Answer (score 10):

You have declared a different friend function to the one you are trying to use. You need

```
friend bool operator< (const X& a, const X& b);
//                     ^^^^^       ^^^^^
```

In any case, it would make no sense for a comparison operator to take non-const references.