# How can I overload a 'less than' operator in my C++ class in order to compare consts?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload the less than operator '<' in my class as follows:

```
//header file

class HuffmanNode{
  private:
    ...
    ...
    int frequency;

  public:
    ...
    ...
    bool operator<(const HuffmanNode &rhs); //overload less than operator
};
```

---

```
//cpp file

bool HuffmanNode::operator<(const HuffmanNode &rhs){
  return frequency < rhs.frequency;
}
```

---

I want to be able to compare the nodes as follows:

```
bool HuffmanTree::compareNode(const HuffmanNode &a, const HuffmanNode &b){
  if (a < b){
    return true;
  }
  else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

---

The problem I'm having is finding a way to compare the two nodes as consts. I get an error saying that my operator overloading method needs to be marked as const but changing the code in the header to

```
const bool operator<(const HuffmanNode &rhs);
```

and the cpp file code to

```
const bool HuffmanNode::operator<(const HuffmanNode &rhs){
  return frequency < rhs.frequency;
}
```

doesn't seem to remove the error.

I have checked out [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18646526/overloading-less-than-operator) but using the friend keyword didn't seem to work either.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You want `bool operator<(const HuffmanNode &rhs) const;`. Note the position of `const`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the concept of usage and positioning of the keyword `const`.

Just to clarify:

```
const T functionName(something);
```

means your `functionName` returns something of the type T and that is a constant.

Now this:

```
T functionName(something) const;
```

means your `functionName` returns something of the type T and that method is not changing anything in the instance and it is safe to use it even with the objects declared as `const`.

The 2nd option is the one you are looking for.